# Flex3 AdvancedDataGrid : how to add a new column based on existing one?

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

I have a AdvancedDataGrid in flex3 (Flex 3) with 4 columns:

- id : int
- category : String
- name     : String
- isPreferred : Boolean

And I would like to add a fifth column

- favorite : Image

  The value of favorite will be based on the value of isPreferred : if true, then favorite will be a read-heart-icon, if false, a grey-heart-icon.
  Thanks for your help.

Below is my code :

- the mxml content

  <xml version="1.0"?>
  <mx:Application 
   xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" applicationComplete="init()">
      <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import com.test.Purchase;
    [Embed(source="..\assets\coeur_rouge.png")]
    public static const ICON_FAVORITE:Class;
    [Embed(source="..\assets\coeur_gris.png")]
    public static const ICON_NEUTRAL:Class;
    [Bindable]
    public var myAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    public function init() :void {
  var aPurchase:Purchase=new Purchase();
  var anotherPurchase:Purchase= new Purchase();
  aPurchase.id=120;
  aPurchase.category="category1";
  aPurchase.name="advantage 2";
  aPurchase.isPreferred=true;
  myAC.addItem(aPurchase);
  anotherPurchase.id=220;
  anotherPurchase.category="category2";
  anotherPurchase.name="Nintendo DS";
  anotherPurchase.isPreferred=false;
      myAC.addItem(anotherPurchase);}
  ]]>
        </mx:Script>
  <?mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dg" width="500" height="150" dataProvider="{myAC}">
        <mx:groupedColumns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="id" headerText="ID" width="300"/> 
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="category" headerText="Category" width="400"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name" width="900"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Fav?" dataField="isPreferred" width="700"/>
        </mx:groupedColumns>
        </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
      </mx:Application>

  - the data object  in action script
    public class Purchase
    {
    public function Purchase() {

    }

    private var _id:int = -1;
    private var _category:String = null;
    private var _productName:String = null;
    private var _preferred:Boolean=false;

    public function get id():int {
        return _id;
    }

    public function set id(pId:int):void {
        _id = pId;
    }

    public function get category():String {
        return _category;
    }

    public function set category(pCategory:String):void {
        _category = pCategory;

    ```
    if ((_category == null) || (_category == "")) {               
        _category = "Default Category";
    }
    ```

    }

    public function get name():String {
        return _productName;
    }

    public function set name(pName:String):void {
        _productName = pName;

    ```
    if ((_productName == null) || (_productName == "")) {
        _productName = "default product name";
        category = _productName;
     }
    ```

    }

    public function get isPreferred() : Boolean {
        return _preferred;
    }

    public function set isPreferred(pPreferred:Boolean) :void {
        _preferred=pPreferred;
    }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this you'll need an `itemRenderer`. Something like this should work:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="favorite">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
            <mx:Image source="{data.isPreferred ? ICON_FAVORITE : ICON_NEUTRAL}">
                <mx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        [Embed(source="..\assets\coeur_rouge.png")]
                        public static const ICON_FAVORITE:Class;

                        [Embed(source="..\assets\coeur_gris.png")]
                        public static const ICON_NEUTRAL:Class;
                    ]]>
                </mx:Script>
            </mx:Image>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
```

Please keep in mind that this piece of code is not reusable. If you need to use columns that show images a lot I recommend implementing a custom `ImageColumn` that extends `mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn`, has some kind of `imageFunction` as property and uses a custom `itemRenderer` which would use the column's `imageFunction` to show the appropriate image.

Comment: Gerhard you`re right: I wanted to illustrate my question. Can you suggest a simplier alternative (than extending AdvancedDataGridColumn) as I am new in flex3. How would you do that?

Comment: The _simple_ solution is the one I posted in the code snippet above. It uses an `Image` as `itemRenderer` where the `source` changes depending on the value of `data.isPreferred`. I've also outlined how you could implement an `ImageColumn`. I'd implement an `imageFunction` for the column (like its `labelFunction`). The custom renderer can access the column through its `listData`. Try it yourself. It's not that complicated when you understand how columns and renderers work. Please post another question if you want to create such an `ImageColumn` and have a specific question.

Comment: I test the solution proposed, but this is not compiling               &lt;mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="favorite"&gt;       &lt;mx:itemRenderer&gt; &lt;mx:Component&gt;       &lt;mx:Image source="{data.isPreferred ? ICON_FAVORITE : ICON_NEUTRAL}"/&gt;       &lt;/mx:Component> &lt;/mx:itemRenderer&gt; &ltl;/mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn&gt;

Comment: -1120: Access of undefined property ICON_NEUTRAL.
 -1120: Access of undefined property ICON_FAVORITE.

Comment: Gerhard, appart from this visibility issue (looks like variable are not visible inside mx:itemrenderer and mx:component) everything works fine. I just put the string constants. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you remove the `<mx:Script>` from the code snippet? The item renderer can't access your constants in your application. They have to be inside the renderer.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered so that others know that it is resolved.

Comment: yes I do, but the access issue remains. But, you made my day. Thanks. How do I mark the question as answered?

Comment: That's why you have to put the constants _inside_ the item renderer (like I did). You can't access anything that's ouside. Well, at least not easily...